# How can I include multiple scopes in one SpotifyOAuth object?

Tags: python, authorization, spotify, spotipy, scopes

I am trying to pass multiple scopes to one token in order to have to enter the URL that I was redirected only once. I have created a class `Spotify` which inside there I initialize the **SpotifyOAuth object**

```
class Spotify():
"""Spotify class that contains plenty of methods to handle your user or retrieve data"""

def __init__(self, cid, secret) -> None:

    self.cid = cid
    self. Secret = secret

    scope = 'user-read-private user-read-recently-played'     

    # Get the token so we don't need to access every time
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(scope, client_id=self.cid, client_secret=self. Secret)
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    
    self. Username, self.followers, self.id = try_to_login(sp)      
    self.sp = sp
```

The scope for `user-read-private` seems to work well but when I am trying to call `self.sp.current_user_recently_played(limit=50)` I get this error:

```
 return self._get(
File "C:\Users\kyria\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 321, in _get
 return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\kyria\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 291, in _internal_call
 raise SpotifyException(
spotipy.exceptions.SpotifyException: http status: 403, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played?limit=50:
Insufficient client scope, reason: None
```

I tried to define the scope according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56173066/how-to-solve-insufficient-client-scope-in-python-using-spotipy) as you can see in the code and also in form of `scope = 'user-read-private,user-read-recently-played'` and `scope = ['user-read-private', 'user-read-recently-played']` according to the [official documentation](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.22.1/#spotipy.client.Spotify.current_user_saved_albums).

How can I achieve of working with multiple scopes at one SpotifyOAuth object if none of these 3 work?

Answer (score 0):

The Get Recently Played Tracks API on Spotify specifically deals with user-related data.
The information you are trying to access is tied to a user's account, and therefore, it is essential to have the user's authorization to access their recently played tracks.

You need to have two conditions

#### #1 Authorized Code Flow + #2 `user-read-recently-played` Scope

This diagram shows what is different from Spotify documentation.

[Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/) vs. [Client Credentials Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/)

403 error is an `Insufficient client scope` error.
[image]

I think you miss either one, maybe missed the scope or not the user login required code flow step.

[image]

This python code will work using `spotipy` v 2.22.1

Save as `get-songs.py`

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import os

# Set your Spotify API credentials as environment variables, it will pick by spotipy API
os.environ["SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID"] = "<your client ID>"
os.environ["SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET"] = "<your client Secret>"
os.environ["SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI"] = "<your App's registered redirect URI>"

# Just this scope good enough to get user_recently_played API
scope = "user-read-recently-played"

# This API call raise web browser and ask user login for getting callback with Authorization Code flow
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope))

# After get token, can call real API
recently_played = sp.current_user_recently_played()

# from the result, we picked up the songs track information
for idx, item in enumerate(recently_played["items"]):
    track = item["track"]
    print(idx, track['artists'][0]['name'], " – ", track['name'])
```

Install dependency

```
pip install spotipy
```

Run it

```
python get-songs.py
```

User Login Steps
[image]

Result
[image]

If you want to using Flaks & requests (low level) instead of `spotipy` (high level)
in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75667796/how-to-handle-web-based-login-from-a-docker-container-using-python-and-flask/75669742#75669742)

This Client Credentials Flow [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75690664/how-could-i-create-a-dataset-with-data-about-music-such-as-songs-albums-artist)

Comment: `os` is a build-in module; you don't have to install it.

Comment: Thanks for your sharp eye. I updated it.